# How to get file's contents on Git using LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: c#, .net, git, version-control, libgit2sharp

I checked code in `BlobFixture.cs` and found some tests about reading file's contents like below.

```
using (var repo = new Repository(BareTestRepoPath))
{
    var blob = repo.Lookup<Blob>("a8233120f6ad708f843d861ce2b7228ec4e3dec6");

    var contentStream = blob.GetContentStream();
    Assert.Equal(blob.Size, contentStream.Length);

    using (var tr = new StreamReader(contentStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string content = tr.ReadToEnd();
        Assert.Equal("hey there\n", content);
    }
}
```

But I cannot find a test that getting file's contents based on file's name. Is it possible to do that, if so how?

Comment: Add `:your/file/path.txt` to the end of the SHA string as [@nulltoken points out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264430/download-one-file-from-remote-git-show-using-libgit2sharp#comment93433585_53265220)

Answer (score 27):

Each `Tree` holds a collection of `TreeEntry`s. A `TreeEntry` holds some metadata (name, mode, oid, ...) about a referenced `GitObject`. The `GitObject` can be accessed through the `Target` property of a `TreeEntry` instance.

Most of the time, a `TreeEntry` will point to a `Blob` or another `Tree`.

The `Tree` type exposes an indexer which accepts a path to easily retrieve the finally pointed at `TreeEntry`. As a convenience method, the `Commit` exposes such an indexer as well.

Thus your code could be expressed this way.

```cs
using (var repo = new Repository(BareTestRepoPath))
{
    var commit = repo.Lookup<Commit>("deadbeefcafe"); // or any other way to retrieve a specific commit
    var treeEntry = commit["path/to/my/file.txt"];

    Debug.Assert(treeEntry.TargetType == TreeEntryTargetType.Blob);
    var blob = (Blob)treeEntry.Target;

    var contentStream = blob.GetContentStream();
    Assert.Equal(blob.Size, contentStream.Length);

    using (var tr = new StreamReader(contentStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string content = tr.ReadToEnd();
        Assert.Equal("hey there\n", content);
    }
}
```

Comment: This sort of works and gets me part of the way there, Thanks!  The problem here though is that the commit will only contain the files modified in that commit. I am still looking for a way to get a specific file at specified repo path, regardless of when it was checked it. I also have no way, ahead of time, of knowing the sha1 hash for a particular commit, nor do I really care in this scenario. I will post an answer if I find one.

Comment: A commit isn't a diffgram. It's a snapshot. As such, it contains all the files that were in the working directory when it was generated.

Comment: From the command line, I found out how to do what I wanted. I can do a sparse checkout of a subdirectory and then do a shallow clone of depth=1 so I only get the history of the head revision. I'm writing some shell commands to call the command line and will post it when its done.

Comment: Great answer. @DanCsharpster (which I understand you most likely have moved on with your life by now) for me the branch commit at the head tip is what I am always looking for, like: string trackedBranchName = $"{ORIGIN_NAME}/{branchToCheckout}";
            Branch trackedBranch = m_repo.Branches[trackedBranchName];
            string currentBranchTipAtOrigin = trackedBranch.Tip.Id.ToString();