# Download one file from remote (git show) using libgit2sharp

Tags: c#, git, f#, libgit2, libgit2sharp

Using `git show`, I can fetch the contents of a particular file from a particular commit, *without changing the state of my local clone*:

```
$ git show <file>
$ git show <commit>:<file>
```

How can I achieve this programatically using [libgit2sharp](/questions/tagged/libgit2sharp)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-cat-file):

`$ git show 807736c691865a8f03c6f433d90db16d2ac7a005:a.txt`

Is equivalent to the code below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using LibGit2Sharp;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pathToFile = "a.txt";
            var commitSha = "807736c691865a8f03c6f433d90db16d2ac7a005";
            var repoPath = @"path/to/repo";

            using (var repo =
                new Repository(repoPath))
            {
                var commit = repo.Commits.Single(c => c.Sha == commitSha);
                var file =  commit[pathToFile];

                var blob = file.Target as Blob;
                using (var content = new StreamReader(blob.GetContentStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    var fileContent = content.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(fileContent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could leverage the `Lookup<T>()`method which accepts an extended sha1 syntax:

`var c = repo.Lookup<Commit>("807736c691865a8f03c6f433d90db16d2ac7a005:a.txt");` 

(cf. https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/f8e2d42ed9051fa5a5348c1a13d006f0cc069bc7/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/RepositoryFixture.cs#L466-L482). Note: This won't "download" from the remote, but will harvest the local git repository (as `git show` does)

Comment: Sorry, that would be `var b = repo.Lookup<Blob>("807736c691865a8f03c6f433d90db16d2ac7a005:a.txt");` :-/

Answer (score 0):

As nulltoken [says in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264430/download-one-file-from-remote-git-show-using-libgit2sharp/53265220#comment93422725_53265220), `Lookup<T>()` [can use](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/f8e2d42ed9051fa5a5348c1a13d006f0cc069bc7/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/RepositoryFixture.cs#L466-L482) colon-pathspec syntax.

```cs
using (var repo = new Repository(repoPath))
{
    // The line below is the important one.
    var blob = repo.Lookup<Blob>(commitSha + ":" + path);

    using (var content = new StreamReader(blob.GetContentStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var fileContent = content.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(fileContent);
    }
}
```

The tagged line is the change from [Andrzej Gis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53265220/241211). It replaces the `commit =`, `file =`, and `blob =` lines. Also, `commitSha` can be any refspec: `v3.17.0`, `HEAD`, `origin/master`, etc.